# A tool to measure signal strength of wireless

Tags: wireless

I want to know if there exists any command line option or GUI tool (Ubuntu 11.10) so that I can measure the strength of wireless signal at a given location. I have a house where the wireless is not easily accessible at all corners I want to know at which corners or rooms the signal is weak.

Comment: It might be easier to use a smartphone/tablet and an app like Wifi Analyzer rather than wandering round holding a laptop open.

Comment: A lot of useful information could be found [8 Linux Commands: To Find Out Wireless Network Speed, Signal Strength And Other Information](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-find-out-wireless-network-speed-signal-strength.html) - also about `iwconfig` and `wavemon` as in answers.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

On the command line you can use `iwconfig` and look for "Link Quality" and "Signal level" values.

When walking around with a netbook I often use this command which updates the output of iwconfig every second:

`watch -n1 iwconfig`

Comment: @RamonSuarez Why run it with sudo? It works without. Tested on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Doesn't show Link Quality or Signal level on Lubuntu 14.04 unless I run it with sudo.

Comment: I can confirm @gmatht's claim. Doesn't show Link Quality or Signal level until run with `sudo`. Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Worked just fine for me in Kubuntu 14.04 without sudo. Link quality and signal level are displayed.

Comment: I use `alias wifi='iwconfig wlan0 | egrep  -o  '\''Bit Rate=[0-9.]+ Mb/s|Tx-Power=off|ESSID:.*'\'''`

Comment: It shows them on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS without sudo.  Good answer.

Answer (score 107):

## [wavemon](https://github.com/uoaerg/wavemon)

A console app with color display and lots of easy to read information.

To install it enter the following commands:

```
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install wavemon
```

To run it enter:

```
 wavemon
```

[image: wavemon in action]

Comment: Requires deprecated wireless extensions, doesn't work with modern `cfg80211`

Comment: worked for me! (16.04, with a one year old Thinkpad)

Comment: wavemon stopped working for me in Ubuntu 16.04. I guess the problem is now in unique names of adapters which are 15 characters long in my case. It detects the adapter but it says "NO INTERFACE DATA" in Levels. Statistics and Info are also empty. It only shows Interface and Network data correctly.

Comment: This is working fine for me on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.  I am using a rt2800usb adapter.  This is the one I was looking for.   TNX

Comment: Here is a tip:  In order to use the F3 Scan function, you need to run wavemon with sudo.

Comment: Works great on ubuntu 20.04. i am using 0.8.2.  You can use an older version of wavemon if your wifi driver supports the older wireless extensions or the newer version to support the newer standards.

Comment: thats beautiful, thanks

Answer (score 18):

A prettier one:

```
watch -n1 "awk 'NR==3 {print \"WiFi Signal Strength = \" \$3 \"00 %\"}''' /proc/net/wireless"
```

Source: http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/06/display-wifi-signal-strength-in-real.html

Comment: You need to run it with sudo

Comment: This is not the true percentage of wifi signal strength. So I did a small fix: `watch -n1 "awk 'NR==3 {printf(\"WiFi Signal Strength = %.0f%%\\n\",\$3*10/7)}' /proc/net/wireless"`

Comment: Mine shows me 70/70 on iwconfig which mean 100%, so with awk its shows me 70% signal strenght, which is untrue. You need divide the two numbers times 100 to get the real percantage. using rtl8198. But still a neat one liner i can use on OSD

Answer (score 1):

With a small modification to measure the quality of the link (Link quality) and the signal level (Signal level).

```
   watch -n1 -d "awk '{print NR == 3 \" WiFi Link Quality = \ "int (\ $ 3 * 1.428571429) \"% (\ "\ $ 3 \" 00 / 70.00) \ "; print \" level WiFi = \ "\ $ 4 \" 00 dBm \ "} '' '/ proc / net / wireless" signal
```

Note: The -d switch to watch highlights values ​​when they change (highlight Changes Between updates).

Answer (score 0):

A command line option that does not require installation of additional software is the `iwconfig` command. To get quality of a connection simply run

```
iwconfig wls8 | grep -i --color quality
```

- Output:

  ```
    Link Quality=56/70  Signal level=-54 dBm
  ```

`wls8` may not be applicable to you, so replace it with whatever option you need. Or simply, run `iwconfig` to see all output.

Here is a blog post that describes plenty of other options [8 Linux Commands: To Find Out Wireless Network Speed, Signal Strength And Other Information](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-find-out-wireless-network-speed-signal-strength.html)