# How can I allow my computer to use more bandwidth?

Tags: networking, download-speed

So I've been trying many things to make get my computer (Ubuntu 16.04) to use more bandwidth. When I go into my WiFi connection information I can see the speed is 144Mb/s but when downloading something weather it is on my browser or applications like steam it only uses 250Kb/s instead.

I've tried to do many solutions such as many of the solutions found here https://itsfoss.com/speed-up-slow-wifi-connection-ubuntu/ and here, but I have had no luck.
(there are a couple I didn't try mostly because they are for older than 11.04)

I have done a speed test and these are my results: https://www.speedtest.net/result/9120633370.png 
(I would be pretty happy if I at least got that on my downloads!)

I hope you all can help me 'cause I'm tired of slow downloads. Thank you! :)

To: Nmath
The main problem is that my computer is only using 250Kb/s rather than the speed tests given 838Kb/s or my "speed" in the connection information.

To: Melebius (thanks)
many other systems such as my PS4 will get 2Mb/s and it is right under my PC. It is some distance from the access point I used one of the links you used and got a connection strength of 62 with 54 Mbits/s.

What I found: my WiFi adapter is not supported by Ubuntu Im using a Tp-link T6E, although it works it is slow as it is not supported :( 
(I don't know how to close this, and I'd rather not solve it so yeah, and I would like to save this for others using a Archer T6E thinking why it is bad.)

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Have you tried with other OS? Or with wired connection? Was there any difference? Is your WiFi signal strong enough, i.e. isn’t your computer too far from the access point? Isn’t the WiFi band congested around you? To check your connection, see [A tool to measure signal strength of wireless](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95676/a-tool-to-measure-signal-strength-of-wireless) and [Is there a tool like wifi analyzer for ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/237777/is-there-a-tool-like-wifi-analyzer-for-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

> although it works it is slow as it is not supported

That is a contradiction: it either works and is supported or it does not work and is not supported. Working and not supported is not possible. TP-Link Archer T6E uses a Broadcom chip.

You need the Broadcom proprietary driver (`bcmwl`). Those are likely on the ISO in the `/pool` directory. Enable the CD-rom repository in Software Sources, and in a terminal session do ...

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

That will install the kernel modules needed to start using it.

In case you can connect to the internet wired, USB tethering, or a hotspot you can also do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get --reinstall install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Before you start with this 1st check the common commands related to wireless and see if the commands identify your card and if a driver is active. You might have the wrong driver installed. There is a script called [wireless-info](https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info) that gathers all the data you need. Also install

```
sudo apt install pastebinit
```

That enables the script to make you a forum optimized paste that you can use to post on ubuntuforums so someone else can analyse it.

But again: a wireless either works or it does not work. And when it works it is supported. Anything related to speed is more likely to be related to settings: for instance the channel can be important. You can set that at your router.

Comment: Currently trying your answer will tell you the outcome soon (thank you), however I would like to show this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HardwareSupportComponentsWirelessNetworkCardsTP-Link#PCI
do ctrl + F and paste this: TL-WN851N  to find what i mean by it isn't supported.

Comment: Please do not use FAQs that refer to Ubuntu 11.10. That is NINE YEARS old. Person here has it working after realizing it was not seated correctly: https://linuxforums.org.uk/index.php?topic=12874.15 using `sudo modprobe ath9k`  in 2016.

Comment: Mind though that the I would ditch the card and get one that uses an Intel chipset  ;-)